# How to show a local Markdown file in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markdown

I have a project and I want to show the content in local Markdown file. It seems that JavaScript cannot read local Markdown straightly. How can I do it?

My project is Vue 3 so some plugins cannot be used.

Comment: What do you mean by "local"? On the server? Or on the user's hard drive?